# React cannot extract first character of string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to display first character in string using charAt(0) does not work.

```
{userNameFirstChar.charAt(0)}
```

**Error:-**

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')

Comment: Is the variable actually defined?

Comment: Can you post the code fragment where you initialize the `userNameFirstChar` variable? Looks like it is `undefined`

Comment: @RuslanBakeyev yes it was undefined solved it using optional chaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using optional chaining it works

```
{userNameFirstChar?.charAt(0)}
```